# ¿Cómo llamar una función de una pantalla desde otra pantalla en Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, callback

Buenas tardes a tod@s.

Soy un desarrollador novato en el mundillo del framework Flutter y terminando de desarrollar una aplicación me ha surgido un problema.

Necesito llamar a una función de una pantalla desde otra pantalla, es decir, con una especie de Callback o algo similar, el problema está en que en Flutter no he conseguido nada con éxito debido a que no he encontrado nada.

Para ser más concreto, necesito actualizar el vector de una pantalla para su muestreo mediante una llamada void, ésta va consultando a una base de datos, pero el problema está en que como tengo varias pestañas, a priori pensé en utilizar hebras, pero eso puede llegar a ser muy ineficiente.

Entonces necesito una herramienta para el llamado de ese void desde otra ventana.

Ejemplo:

Tengo una función que incrementa un contador en la pantalla principal, y desde otra ventana, quiero llamar a esa función para incrementar para el momento que regrese a la pantalla principal, se haya incrementado el contador.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola para lo que quieres hacer tendrias que usar un gestor de estado, hay varios te mencionare algunos FlutterBloc,Getx,Provider, etc.
En youtube hay varios ejemplos, usa el que te sea mas entendible.

Comment: Podes usar otra clase donde guardar el estado, como un singleton, y luego llamarla en ambas pantallas, o ya usar un gestor de estados un poco más complejo como provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer lo que mencionas debes usar un gestor de estado dentro de tu aplicación, te recomiendo que uses Provider ya que es el mas sencillo. Puedes encontrar mas información directamente en la pagina del plugin:

https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: Exacto, he podido solucionar este problema gracias a Provider, y gracias a esta herramienta se me ocurren diversas funcionalidades nuevas para mis futuros desarrollos. Muchas gracias.